# A possible memory reorder in go routines?

Tags: go, memory, concurrency

The `go` program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var x int
    threads := runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0) // get max cpus,
    for i := 0; i < threads; i++ {
        go func() {
            for {
                x++
            }
        }()
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)
    fmt.Printf("threads = %v, x = %v\n", threads, x)
}
```

---

On my machine (`Linux`), the printed result is:

> threads = 8, x = 0

---

**The questions are:**

- Why `x` is `0`, is that some kind of memory reorder in cpu caches?
- What kind of optimization did the compiler / os (`Linux`) / cpu  do on the program?

Comment: "What kind of optimization did the compiler / os (Linux) / cpu do on the program?" if you really wanted to know, you'd have to be 100% specific and clear on what compiler, version, os architecture etc. Every compiler has the freedom to do whatever it wants, and it most likely changes by version. In this case, I see what you describe on go1.19.1 darwin/amd64. You could disassemble the code but my guess is that the compiler keeps `x` in the `main` function in a CPU register and doesn't reload it from memory since it doesn't need to according to the Go memory model.

Comment: Your e code is malformed as it's racy. Nothing to see or learn here.

Comment: @Volker The race is on purpose, to test the memory reorder behavior, read the title.

Comment: Racy code is racy and doesn't allow to test anything, it's just wrong. It's a bit like doing math with unsound prove systems and trying to learn something about natural numbers.

Comment: If you pretend the `time.Sleep` isn't there, does the output make sense to you?

Answer (score -1):

`x` is `0` because there is a memory race. Since a shared variable is read concurrently by at least one more goroutine without explicit synchronization, there is no guarantee that the read from the variable will see the writes performed to it.

It is hard to say what kind of optimizations were done. One possibility is that the compiler chose not to assume `x` is 0 because it is not modified in that goroutine. There are many other possibilities.

Comment: If u run it many times, it's always `0`, seems that's guaranteed. Since it's not random, thus I think the first part is not enough to explain it.

Comment: In another platform, you may observe different values. A race condition not only implies inconsistent behavior in multiple runs of the same program, but also inconsistent behavior across platforms.